# I'm trying to swap first and last integer of an integer but when I input 1234 the output is 1351

Tags: c

Edit:Im trying to swap first and Last integers

When I input `1234` I can't get the output `4321` instead I get `1351`.
I checked if `digits` was 4 and `firstDigit` was 1, they both were correct but I'm not getting the output I want.

Can you please help me?
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int firstDigit, lastDigit, digits = 0, number;
  
    printf("Input number \n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
  
    firstDigit = number;
  
    do {
        firstDigit /= 10;  
    } while (firstDigit > 9);

    digits = log10(number) + 1;
  
    lastDigit = number % 10;
  
    number = number - firstDigit * 10 * digits;
    number = number - lastDigit;
    number = number + lastDigit * 10 * digits;
    number = number + firstDigit; 
   
    printf("%d", number);
  
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** fixed the problem thank you guys.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int firstDigit, lastDigit, digits = 0, number;
  
    printf("Input number \n");
  
    scanf("%d", &number);
  
    firstDigit = number;
  
    do
    {
        firstDigit /= 10;  
    }
    while (firstDigit > 9);

    digits = log10(number);
    lastDigit = number % 10;
    number = number - firstDigit * pow(10, digits);
    number = number - lastDigit;
    number = number + lastDigit * pow(10, digits);
    number = number + firstDigit; 
   
    printf("%d", number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: `firstDigit*10*digits` is `40`... not `1000`

Comment: I've edited your question, in order to make it clearer. Please have a look. In top of this, this kind of question can easily be solved using a debugger. Do you know how to use a debugger? In case no, which one are you using and what kind of problems do you encounter?

Comment: Fixed the problem thank you guys ı needed to use the pow() function i edited the post with the correct code

Comment: Using `pow` and `log10` is a **very** bad idea for this problem

Comment: Why is that and how can i improve the code?

Comment: Due to the limited precision of floating point representations, large integers cannot be exactly represented, leading to incorrect results for both `log10()` and `pow()`. Use integer arithmetics for this kind of problem.

Comment: If the expected output is `4321`, you should not just swap the first and last digits, you should reverse the base 10 representation of the number.

Comment: Your problem has no relation to numbers (to arithmetic). It would be the same as transforming `"frob"` ==> `"brof"`. I suggest you treat it as a ***string*** problem: `printf("Input number:"); char number[20]; fgets(number, 20, stdin); number[strcspn(number, "\n")] = '\0'; ...`

Comment: The exercise was about loops i  havent learned strings yet

Comment: Please edit your question clarifying the purpose of the program. Do you have to reverse the whole number or just swap the first and last digits?

Comment: "i havent learned strings yet" ... good reason to treat the problem arithmetically :-) **Suggestion**: when you learn strings come back to this problem and solve it with new knowledge.

Comment: I will pmg thanks and Bob i edited the post

Comment: @Mdmn Note; "i havent learned strings yet" --> `"Input number \n"` is a _string_.

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to modify the number so its representation in base 10 has the same digits in the opposite direction.

Here is a simple implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number, result = 0;
  
    printf("Input number \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &number) == 1) {
        while (number != 0) {
            result = result * 10 + number % 10;
            number /= 10;
        }
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you just need to swap the first and last digits, the approach is different: you need to determine the largest power of 10 below the number:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int first_digit, last_digit, number, pow_10, result;
  
    printf("Input number \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &number) == 1) {
        power_10 = 1;
        while (number / power_10 > 9) {
            power_10 *= 10;
        }
        first_digit = number / power_10;
        last_digit = number % 10;
        result = last_digit * power_10 + number % power_10 - last_digit + first_digit;
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```